# How to wp_enqueue script from child theme in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a jquery script to edit some parts of the wordpress page.

This is the code that I have tried so far in **functions.php**

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    if (is_page('21')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
            '/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');
```

And this is the simple jQuery script that I want to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(function() {
        alert('tables test alert');
    });
</script>
```

The script above is not loading. Please help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you check that your is_page condition is true? and you are using get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?if it is really not loaded please check develooper console for an error.

Comment: if your code is in `.js` file why you use script tags there? `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your include function looks right, you must remove script tags `<script type="text/javascript">` from your `.js` file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to make changes for a script in a specific page, you might as well try the Custom Script Integration plugin instead of meddling with functions.php. This plugin will let you add your code under head or body for individual pages so it will be easier to manage scripts.

Link to plugin: http://www.wpwox.com/wp-plugin/custom-script-integration/